# Angular 8: Campo CPF/CNPJ retornando vazio na edição ao alterar a máscara dinamicamente com Ngx-Mask!

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-8

Meu input > cliente.html

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-2">
    <label for="tipo">Tipo Pessoa:</label>
    <select name="tipo" class="form-control form-control-sm" (change)="aoAlterarTipoPessoa($event.target.value)"
        [(ngModel)]="cliente.tipo" id="tipo">
        <option value="1">FÍSICA</option>
        <option value="2">JURÍDICA</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-2">
    <label for="cpf"> {{ cpfLabel }} </label>
    <input name="cpf" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cpf" [mask]="cpfMask" [(ngModel)]="cliente.cpf">
    <span *ngIf="send && !valid && cliente.tipo == 1" class="text-danger">CPF Inválido</span>
    <span *ngIf="send && !valid && cliente.tipo == 2" class="text-danger">CNPJ Inválido</span>
</div>
```

Minha função > cliente.ts

```
aoAlterarTipoPessoa(event){
    if(event == 1){
      this.tipoPessoa = true;
      this.cpfLabel = 'CPF:';
      this.rgLabel = 'RG:';
      this.nomeLabel = 'Nome:';
      this.apelidoLabel = 'Apelido:';
      this.cpfMask = '000.000.000-00';
      this.send = false;
      this.valid = null;
    }else{
      this.tipoPessoa = false;
      this.cpfLabel = 'CNPJ:';
      this.rgLabel = 'IE:';
      this.nomeLabel = 'Razão Social:';
      this.apelidoLabel = 'Fantasia:';
      this.cpfMask = "00.000.000/0000-00";
      this.send = false;
      this.valid = null;
    }
  }
```

metodo ngOnInit > cliente.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    let codigo = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];     **Aqui pego o codigo passado na url**
    if(codigo){
        this.httpClient.get(this.url.concat(codigo))   **se existir realizo a busca do cliente**
        .pipe(
            map((cliente: any)=>{
                this.aoAlterarTipoPessoa(cliente.tipo);  ** Aqui chamo a função passando o tipo **
                return cliente;
            })
         ).subscribe(
            response => this.cliente = response
         );
    }else{
        this.aoAlterarTipoPessoa(1);
    }
}
```

O erro ocorre que ao editar um cliente, o campo cpf/cnpj continua funcionando a máscara dinâmica, porém o valor na edição vem em branco!
Estava realizando uns testes e ao comentar as linhas `this.cpfMask = '000.000.000-00';` e `this.cpfMask = "00.000.000/0000-00";` da função `aoAlterarTipoPessoa()`, os valores são retornados normalmente, porém perdem a função da máscara!

Lembrando que quando digito o CPF/CNPJ e faço a alteração manualmente pelo seletor, os campos não somem e a máscara continua funcionando, só vem o campo vazio do CPF/CNPJ na edição!

Comment: verifica se o valor esta vindo como string ou number

Comment: O valor do cpf vem como string!

Comment: Resolvi de uma forma um pouco diferente, mas resolvi!

Não estou mais realizando a máscara de forma dinâmica, mas sim usando dois inputs e usando *ngIf para ocultar ou exibir de acordo o tipo selecionado!

`<input *ngIf="cliente.tipo == 1" name="cpf" class="form-control form-control-sm" mask="000.000.000-00" [(ngModel)]="cliente.cpf">
  <input *ngIf="cliente.tipo == 2" name="cpf" class="form-control form-control-sm" mask="00.000.000/0000-00" [(ngModel)]="cliente.cpf">`